# How do I tar a folder or directory with all of it's files except leave out files from certain folders?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

Looking all over for a solution, but can't find it. Somehow I am always trying unique scenarios that no one ever thinks of. Weird. Anyway here is the scenario...

```
foldertop (keep)
-foldersub (keep)
--foldersubsub (keep)
----foldersubsubsub (keep)
------files (exclude)
----files (exclude)
--files (keep)
-files (keep)
```

I want to tar all directories and subdirectories. I want the entire folder structure, but I don't want all files. I want to keep some files from some folders and leave out other files from other directories.

The only thing i know to do is to exclude the folders of the files i don't want like so:

```
tar -cvf bak_1-28-15.tar --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub foldertop
```

Maybe i can add a star to keep the foldersubsub directory and exclude all the files within it like this:

```
tar -cvf bak_1-28-15.tar --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/* foldertop
```

But that will exclude the foldersubsubsub directory as well. i want to exclude all the files in foldersubsubsub but keep the foldersubsubsub directory.

How can i do this scenario?

tried this without find method. doesn't work:

```
tar -cvf bak_1-28-15.tar --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/* --include=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub/* foldertop
```

the error i get is:

```
tar: unrecognized option '--include=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub'
```

putting include at the end didn't work either, it's still an unrecognized option.

```
tar -cvf bak_1-28-15.tar --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/* --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub/* --include=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub foldertop
```

putting folder at the end without an include in the middle doesn't work either. doesn't give and error, but the foldersubsubsub directory is not included.

```
tar -cvf bak_1-28-15.tar --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/* --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub/* foldertop foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub
```

next going to try star*.star* so i only target files and not folders.  like this:

```
tar -cvf bak_1-28-15.tar --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/*.* --exclude=foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub/*.* foldertop
```

that seems to have done the trick. this works for me since there will be no files without dots, and there will also be no files that begin with a dot.

Comment: I'm assuming that pattern attempt didn't work? It wasn't clear whether you tried it and it failed or whether the "But that ..." was talking about the previous attempt. You could use find/etc. to build the file list and pass that to tar instead of having it recurse from a folder name directly.

Comment: didn't bother to test the one with a star because it's not what i want. it's close but not perfect. i would need to manually add those subsubsub folders after extraction. this example above is simple. there are more subsub folders with their own subsubsub folders.

Comment: Oh... I missed the extra `sub` on that last sentence. Sorry. Yeah, I'd probably use `find` to construct the file listing for something like this.

Comment: don't know how to use find that much. have an example?

Comment: Instead of `--include` try just adding those directories on the end of the command line? (Like `foldertop`?)

Comment: putting include at the end after excludes doesn't work either. same error comes up.

Comment: No, not `--include` at the end. Just the paths directly. `foldertop foldertop/foldersub/foldersubsub/foldersubsubsub`.

Comment: Didn't work, but i tried something that did work. in my exclude options i added .* to the stars, making them star*.star* - this made it so i just target files and not folders.

Comment: `*.*` will only match files with dots in the names, so not `Readme` or `NEWS`, etc. just for the record.

Comment: i know. only dot files will go there and none where they begin with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

```
find foldertop | grep -v "foldersubsubsub/files" | xargs tar -cvf tarFileName.tar
```

should do this.

Comment: This is overly simplistic for the actual goal I think and using `xargs` is potentially dangerous because if the legnth of filenames for found files exceeds the command length limit `xargs` will spawn more than one `tar` process and the second will stomp all over the first commands output.

Comment: Maybe, if you're afraid of length limitation, have a empty tar in place first, then use `xargs -i tar -uvf`

Comment: `-r` might be better than `-u` (I'm assuming `-`u needs to scan the existing tar archive first) but yes, that would help. That being said if you can use `-T /dev/stdin` (or similar) with `tar` then `xargs` isn't necessary.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes. `stdin` is good. But, I'm not sure whether it can handle all types of files, if not all, atleast binary files. If they can, yes, you can employ them.

Comment: You aren't sending the files to tar via `stdin` you are sending the names via stdin.

Comment: Correct. I didn't do, I'm bit skeptical to that as I'm not sure of their level of binary content support.

Comment: Ah, you meant "odd" filenames. Yes, that could be a problem depending on how tar parses the "file" given to `-T`.